# Regex to find words with no more than two of letter "o" each

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, and I need to check whether or not this string contains at least two words that do not contain more than two instances of the letter "O". I am able to successfully check a single (the first) word for the "O" requirement using the following regex pattern:

`^([a-np-z]*o?[a-np-z]*o?[a-np-z]*)[\W]+`

How would I expand upon this pattern to check subsequent words, and to applying to overarching logic to the string as a whole?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of valid and invalid inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it with this Regex:

```
/(?:\b[a-np-z]+\b)|(?:\b[a-np-z]*o[a-np-z]*o?[a-np-z]*\b)/i
```

First parenthesis matches any word that doesn't contain the letter "o". Second one matches any word that has one or two letters "o".

So, if you do:

```
$subject  = "Testing, o, oo, ooo. Not too many triple 'o' words, here are a few: ";
$subject .= "Rosewood, Zoonosis, Morocco...";
preg_match_all("/(?:\\b[a-np-z]+\\b)|(?:\\b[a-np-z]*o[a-np-z]*o?[a-np-z]*\\b)/i", $subject, $matches);
$count = count($matches[0]);

if ($count >= 2) {
    echo "Passed, found $count";
} else {
    echo "Not passed, found $count";
}

// output: Passed, found 13
```

The contents of `$matches[0]` will be:

```
print_r($matches[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => Testing
    [1] => o
    [2] => oo
    [3] => Not
    [4] => too
    [5] => many
    [6] => triple
    [7] => o
    [8] => words
    [9] => here
    [10] => are
    [11] => a
    [12] => few
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reg (Perl) :

```
(\w*o\w*o\w*)+
```

String :

```
pero que me estas contenedoor muchacho sonr tono orco petttae tooorpedo oo
```

Results :

```
Match 1:    contenedoor     18      11
Group 1:    contenedoor     18      11
Match 2:    tono        44       4
Group 1:    tono        44       4
Match 3:    orco        49       4
Group 1:    orco        49       4
Match 4:    tooorpedo       62       9
Group 1:    tooorpedo       62       9
Match 5:    oo      72       2
Group 1:    oo      72       2
```

So now you cant do your `preg_match_all(pattern , input , output`) and count the output size checking if it's greater than two.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 0):

For a single word with double 'o' is

[^\Wo]+o[^\Wo]+o[^\Wo]+

This will exclude any foreign characters and 'o', matches other words and stops at seeing 'o'

For repeating instances

([^\Wo]+o[^\Wo]+o[^\Wo]+\W+)+

Comment: **\w** token - match any word character => It will search words with more then 2 'o'